# how to create a another dock

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to create a dock which will contain some application's icon and at runtime user can add   application to that dock by dragging them to dock. when user click on any app icon present in that dock, that app should lunch

hare I don't want to replace the system dock or i am not trying to create a dock inside a  application . this is just a another dock in system .

so can any one tell me how to setup this dock app.

Comment: Why multiple docks? Will you like it? Or this is just a question for learning purpose?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, NO any how I have to do this . from last 2 days i am working on it still no progress

Comment: You can't start multiple instances of the OSX dock. You can however write an OSX application which mimics its behavior.

Comment: @yiding, hey man I am trying to make a new app like OSX dock . I don't want the multiple instance of OSX dock . pls try to find out the correct meaning of sentence .

Comment: Well, if you want to write such an app then you should just do that. It'll involve a custom rendered window with drag and drop handlers, and probably a bunch of other stuff. Not sure what kind of an answer you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a NSWindow, and set the correct level with `-[NSWindow setLevel:NSDockWindowLevel];`
You can also set a window not to have top bar with buttons and to have transparent contentView.
Then you should handle drag and drop of applications.

Comment: Dock level has been deprecated (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdockwindowlevel?language=objc), and doesn't create another dock icon, but merely floats the window at the same level as the dock.